# iOS/Swift: why contains doesn't work to detect a substring in the .firstIndex function?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, substring, array-indexing

I am using the function .firstIndex to locate a specific substring in an array of arrays.
But when I put the entire string, it works, but if I put only a substring of that string, this doesn't work.

[image]

```
let index = programArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.contains("2021-14-09")}) //Index is nil => bad
let index = programArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.contains("2021-14-09 08:00:00")}) // Index is 0 => good
```

If i use it not in the firstIndex function it works, it is strange...

```
let test = "2021-14-09 08:00:00"
let test2 = test.prefix(10).contains("2021-14-09") // true => good
```

How can I do?

Comment: Where is your string coming from? Why don't you create a json string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use contains(_:), but if you look into the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains) you see:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the sequence contains the given element.

So the whole string has to match if you use contains.